# Problem transferring file via curl in ftp data is lost

Tags: curl, ftp

I faced such a problem when I run the command to transfer a file via `curl` to `ftp` *my server* already has such a `file.txt` file
And it turns out that all the data there is erased and the sent file `file.txt` is written *(via `curl`)*

```
curl -T file.txt  ftp://login: pass@ftp.server.com/http/
```

I need to make it so that the data from above is written to the `file.txt` *(my server no loss!)*

Like in the utility *cat*

```
cat file.txt >> file2.sh
```

How do I do `>>` merge files in `curl`? Are there flags for `curl` in merge?

Comment: have you read the man page, or the output of `curl --help all`?

Answer (score 1):

According with the man page of curl, you can use `-a` or `--append` You can use the `man [application name]` command

```
 -a, --append                                                                                                                 
        (FTP SFTP) When used in an upload, this makes curl append to the target file instead of overwriting it. If the remote 
        file doesn't exist, it will be created.  Note that this flag is ignored by some SFTP servers (including OpenSSH).
```